# 'Initializing data table before use'

Tags: initialization, nullreferenceexception

how can i solve this please ?

i am doing a simple database project and i have a search field i wrote the following code for searching and displaying data in DataGridView  but the 
Null Reference Exception keeps showing up because i'm initializing the table with nothing and yet if i don't do so  i get 'Used Before Initializing warning.

the question is :how can i initialize the table properly .

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    Dim searchText As String = txtSearch.Text
    Dim matchText As String = ""
    Dim rowMatch As Boolean = False
    Dim foundRows As DataTable = Nothing 'this initializig causes the   problem of null exception,But how can i Initialize it then?????


For Each rw As DataRow In dataSet.Tables(0).Rows

        Dim cl As String = rw.Item(1).ToString '  this cell is FirstName  Cell
        If searchText.Length > cl.ToString.Length Then
            matchText = cl.ToString
        Else
            matchText = cl.ToString.Substring(0, searchText.Length)
        End If

        'bellow it adds the Found Row (rw) to the table 
        If (searchText.Equals(matchText) And searchText <> "" And Not foundRows Is Nothing) Then foundRows.Rows.Add(rw)

Next


    'to shows data if the search text field is not empty then show the found matching rows
    If (searchText <> "") Then
        contactView.DataSource = foundRows
    Else ' else show the original tavle again 
        contactView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
    End If
    contactView.Refresh() 'refresh 
End Sub
```

[here is the screenshot of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fW8s.jpg)

i tried to use

```
Dim foundRows As DataTable = New DataTable
```

but it shows **ArgumentException**

***This Row already belongs to another Table***

[i also tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnZ9B.jpg)

but as you can see nothing works please Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes 
i finally got it

i was having a problem in columns

```
Dim foundRows As DataTable = New DataTable("PseuContact")  'this initializig causes the problem of null exception,But how can i Initialize it then?????
   foundRows.Columns.Add("ID")
    foundRows.Columns.Add("First Name")
    foundRows.Columns.Add("Last Name")
    foundRows.Columns.Add("Phone Number")
    foundRows.Columns.Add("Mobile Number")
    foundRows.Columns.Add("Email Address")
```

initializing columns is important when declaring new table

this's been the best